# Derivation tree not rendering

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree

I'm trying to draw a derivation tree for a simple grammar using `tikz-qtree`.

Here is my current code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

% ----------

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{grow'=right}
        \tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
        \Tree [.$SS$ [.$(S)$ $()$]
                [.$(S)$
                    [.$((S))$ $(())$]
                ]
            ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My intended result looks like this:

```
                -(S)------------()                
              -/                                  
            -/                                    
          -/                                      
        -/                                        
      -/                                          
   SS -\                                          
        -\                                        
          -\                                      
            -\                                    
              -\                                  
                -\                                
                  -(S)---------((S))----------(())
```

When I compile the document, I get a bunch of missing end brace complaints "./main.tex:21: Missing } inserted", but the square brackets in the `\Tree` are balanced as far as I can see.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are three different ways to draw the graph

#### `tikz-qtree` solution

Take care of the white space!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

% ----------

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\Tree [.$SS$ [.$(S)$ $()$ ] [.$(S)$ [.$((S))$ $(())$ ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Pure Ti*k*Z solution

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm]
\node (ss) {$SS$};
\node[above right=of ss] (sa) {$(S)$};
\node[right=of sa] (br1) {$()$};
\node[below right=of ss] (sb) {$(S)$};
\node[right=of sb] (ssb) {$((S))$};
\node[right=of ssb] (br2) {$(())$};
\draw (br1) -- (sa) -- (ss) -- (sb) -- (ssb) -- (br2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### `tikzcd` solution

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}]
& (S) \arrow[r] & ()\\
SS \arrow[ru]\arrow[rd] & &\\
& (S) \arrow[r] & ((S)) \arrow[r] & (())
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you point out the difference? What did I mess up?

Comment: @AdamWilliams There _are_ difference: my `[.$(S)$ $()$ ]` is working but your `[.$(S)$ $()$]` is not working (take note of the white space)

Comment: @AdamWilliams You are welcome! Although you were so close, but only one white space is a great deal for this package :) Unfortunately, the error message is not really clear.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to persuade you to switch to `forest`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow=east}
 [$SS$ 
   [$(S)$ $()$]
                [$(S)$
                    [$((S))$ $(())$]
                ]
            ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A tempting proposition - I do prefer forest's syntax!